# Vector assignment problem

Tags: c++, vector

```
#include "iostream"
#include "vector"
using namespace std;

const vector<int>& Getv() 
{
vector<int> w(10);
w[0]=10;
cout<<w.size()<<endl;
return w;
}
//Now when I write in main:
vector<int>v = Getv();//Throws exception
//and the below rows has no effect
vector<int>v;
v=Getv()//w does not change
```

please what is the problem?
Hani Almousli...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're returning a reference to a local variable. When you exit the function it gets destructed.

You need to return a copy:

```
vector<int> Getv() 
{
  vector<int> w(10);
  w[0]=10;
  cout<<w.size()<<endl;
  return w;
}
```

Or you could make `w` static:

```
const vector<int>& Getv() 
{
  static vector<int> w(10);
  w[0]=10;
  cout<<w.size()<<endl;
  return w;
}
```

Also you should use `<>` on your includes since they're part of the standard library.

Comment: Thanks very much, but why i have to write static here and i dont have to write it if i am returning a Student& for example.I mean suppose that i am returning Student& instead of vector<int>?

Comment: static variables are not stored in the stack, so they are not destroyed when the function ends. Then , its legal to return a reference. If you are returning a Student& and your student object is not static, thats undefined behaviour.

Comment: Execuse me but what do you mean by undefined behavior. You meant that it is right but i must not do it.Actually i can not imagine how it works fine because it is logically to be destroyed when the function ends.but when i return Student& it works.
Thank you very much...

Comment: You got lucky, undefined behavior means it could work the way you wanted it to but that's not always the case.

Comment: Hani, just because it worked on your machine this time on this run doesn't mean it's correct. You cannot return a reference to a local-stack allocated object, because when the function ends, it will go away. Static variables live in-between function calls.

Comment: Of course, returning a pointer to a local object is just as bad :)

Comment: Most likely Student& seemed to work because it had no destructor. vector<>'s destructor was called when you left the function and that deleted the data. In either case, the Student or vector<> will have its memory overwritten by later code / other function calls.

Never return a reference (or pointer) to local variables. It will not work, and if it seems to work it will cause subtle issues later.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you confuse return parameter and input argument.
It's safe to pass argument by constant reference:

```
void fun(const vector<int>& arg1)
{
    //something
}
```

In that example you pass only reference, so copy constructor isn't invoked.

But it's dangerous to return reference value (const or not const) from function.
See answer of Bruce above.
Also you can extend reference lifetime:

```
const vector<int>& Getv() 
{
    vector<int> w(10);
    w[0]=10;
    cout<<w.size()<<endl;
    return w;
}

const vector<int>& v = Getv(); //now all ok
```

But I don't recomment this way. It can be source of future bugs.
The best way is returning value of vector.

```
vector<int> Getv() 
{
   vector<int> w(10);
   w[0]=10;
   cout<<w.size()<<endl;
   return w;
}

vector<int>v = Getv();
```

Since there is only 1 return statement you can account for RVO and copy constructor won't be invoke too. it is fast and safe.